# Is it possible to set two div's side by side, while one div is outside of the screen without using display none or width zero?

Tags: html, css, animation, scroll

There is NO problem to set them side by side.
BUT - Can one div be outside of the screen width?

I want to insert DIV2 above DIV1 with animation, while DIV2 is already open and ready to be seen, but I don't want to play with its width or display, only
change is position so it will enter the screen from the side.

The two divs should be 100% width and height. Can that be accomplish some how?
I can set overflow-x to be hidden, so no horizontal scroll, but I think there is a problem with width 100% for both of them.

Please advise.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done with absolute positioning. For 2nd div set width: 100% and left: 100%

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="div1">
    </div>
    <div id="div2">
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#wrapper{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

#div1{
    background: yellow;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

#div2{
    background: green;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 100%;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/p1ga7669/

Comment: Is there a good way to do that in AngularJS?
I saw you use jQuery for the animation.

Comment: I'm not familiar with angular but I think that animation can be made in any possible way. I used jquery in the example just to show the initially invisible div.

Answer (score 0):

The approach you'd like to take wouldn't work with width:100%. In order to use this approach the width of both child divs have to be explicitely set (not in percentage).

Since you're using javascript though, you could try and measure the available width of the parent container and then use that value. If you're using jquery you could use an expression like

> $('#parentContainer').outerWidth()

to get this value.